# After post back update panel Accordion Not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

After post back update panel Accordion Not working.

Below is my script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("DIV.Accordion > DIV.collapsePanelHeader").click(function () {
        $(this).next("DIV.Content").slideToggle("slow");
        $("DIV.Accordion > DIV.Content").not($(this).next("DIV.Content")).slideUp("slow");

    });
});
```

I tried this below script and added above script code inside your script block side but according is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
            $(function () {
                //Your script
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // below will execute after ajax postback
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        OnLoadPage();
    }

    function OnLoadPage() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("DIV.Accordion > DIV.collapsePanelHeader").click(function () {
                $(this).next("DIV.Content").slideToggle("slow");
                $("DIV.Accordion > DIV.Content").not($(this).next("DIV.Content")).slideUp("slow");
            });
        });
    }

    // executes after page load first time
    OnLoadPage();
</script>
```

Comment: how to add plus and minus symbol to slideToggle of your above answer. @Piyush Khatri

Comment: I didn't understand, can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: I need some think like that to my slide  http://jsfiddle.net/aLcZa/3/ . @Piyush Khatri